# Python's string template changes brackets when variable is unset

Tags: python, string, templates

I have Python code which attempts to replace variables using the special syntax $[VARIABLE] (note square brackets) and string.template.safe_substitute(). This is working fine, with the one exception that when an undefined variable is referenced, instead of leaving the reference alone as safe_substitute() is documented to do it replaces the square brackets with curly ones. The advanced use of RE's in templates is not documented in detail (http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) so probably I'm just using them wrong. Ideas?

Here's an example run of the test case; note that everything works fine when the var is defined:

```
% python tmpl.py
===$[UNDEFINED]===
===${UNDEFINED}===

% UNDEFINED=Hello python tmpl.py
===$[UNDEFINED]===
===Hello===
```

And here's the test case itself:

```
import os
from string import Template


# The strategy here is to replace $[FOO] but leave traditional
# shell-type expansions $FOO and ${FOO} alone.
# The '(?!)' below is a guaranteed-not-to-match RE.
class _Replace(Template):
    pattern = r"""
        \$(?:
        (?P<escaped>(?!))               | # no escape char
        (?P<named>(?!))                 | # do not match $FOO, ${FOO}
        \[(?P<braced>[A-Z_][A-Z_\d]+)\] | # do match $[FOO]
        (?P<invalid>)
    )
    """


if '__main__' == __name__:
    text = '===$[UNDEFINED]==='
    tmpl = _Replace(text)
    result = tmpl.safe_substitute(os.environ)
    print text
    print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Template` assumes the brace character is actually a brace:

`string.py:194`:

```
        if braced is not None:
            try:
                return '%s' % (mapping[braced],)
            except KeyError:
                return self.delimiter + '{' + braced + '}'
```

If you think it's a bug, post it up at http://bugs.python.org. Otherwise, I'd recommend just using `{}` as your delimiting character if possible.

Comment: I do think it's a bug, either of the code or documentation variety. Thanks for tracking it down. I guess I could have UTSL-ed too. Another solution, which is the one I went with, was to bring a copy of safe_substitute into the subclass I already had and "fix" it there.